# Ayuda con instalar versiones antiguas php y Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2

por favor necesito ayuda con la instalación de unas dependencias de php y Symfony el problema es que son antiguas y cuando intento instalar me salen errores de  que ya no existen soporte para ellas, como puedo instalar este composer.json que tiene versiones antiguas de todo ?, me toca actualizar todo ? si me toca actualizar , como lo pudiera hacer ? o si hay una forma de que pueda instalar todo esto sin problema.

Lo intente subir a heroku pero me bota

> ERROR: Dependency installation failed! remote:  ! remote:  !     The
>   'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause remote:  ! 
>   may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or remote: 
>   !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
>   remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'. remote:  ! remote:  !
>   Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code, remote: 
>   !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
>   remote:  ! remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to
>   determine the cause of remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code
>   you're pushing is functioning remote:  !     properly, and that all
>   local changes are committed correctly. remote:  ! remote:  !     For
>   more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to

este es mi composer.json

> {
>       "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
>       "license": "MIT",
>       "type": "project",
>       "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
>       "autoload": {
>           "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
>       },
>       "require": {
>           "php": ">=5.3.3",
>           "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
>           "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
>           "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
>           "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
>           "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
>           "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
>           "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
>           "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0.12",
>           "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
>           "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
>           "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.1",
>           "jms/di-extra-bundle": "* 1.5.0",
>           "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "1.1.*@dev",
>           "liuggio/excelbundle": "* 2.1.0",
>           "oro/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master"
>
> ```
> },
> "require-dev": {
>     "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
> },
> "scripts": {
>     "post-root-package-install": [
>         "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
>     ],
>     "post-install-cmd": [
>         "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
>     ],
>     "post-update-cmd": [
>         "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
>   "ComposerScript\\Installer::postPackageUpdate",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
>         "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
>     ]
> },
> "config": {
>     "bin-dir": "bin"
> },
> "extra": {
>     "symfony-app-dir": "app",
>     "symfony-web-dir": "web",
>     "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
>     "incenteev-parameters": {
>         "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
>     },
>     "branch-alias": {
>         "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
>     }
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso lo que hice fue instalar en el proyecto composer.phar contemporáneo a la versión con la que trabaje.
en pasos

1- bajo la versión de composer [descargar composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) en mi caso yo baje la 1.10.0

2-la instalo con el comando

> php composer.phar install

3-pruebo que este todo bien con

> php app/console server:start